# Check specific position of jTextField

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to know, how can I check specific position of `jTextField`? For example, I have typed in a string - `0000-1111`, I want to check if `-` is in the 5th position. How can I do that?

Comment: Use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), and check the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = textField.getText();
int offset = text.indexOf("-");
```

Or a better solution is to use a `JFormattedTextField`. Then you can use a MaskFormatter and make the "-" a part of the mask and just have the user enter the numbers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: @user4285519 glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String.getIndexOf(char)` method.

**OR**

`Str.lastIndexOf( "-" )` method will give you the last occurrence of this character.

```
String Str="get- my index of - char";
System.out.println(Str.indexOf( "-" ));
System.out.println(Str.lastIndexOf( "-" ));
```